# catkin_make_isolated /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<lib_name>

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, catkin-make-isolated, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run catkin_make_isolated on my workspace and it fails.

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'motor_driver_pkg'
==> Building with env: '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/kinematics/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/user/catkin_ws/build_isolated/motor_driver_pkg'
==> make -j6 -l6 in '/home/user/catkin_ws/build_isolated/motor_driver_pkg'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable /home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/motor_driver_pkg/lib/motor_driver_pkg/dc_motor_driver
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkinematics
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/dc_motor_driver.dir/build.make:119: recipe for target '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/motor_driver_pkg/lib/motor_driver_pkg/dc_motor_driver' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/motor_driver_pkg/lib/motor_driver_pkg/dc_motor_driver] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1091: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dc_motor_driver.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dc_motor_driver.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'motor_driver_pkg': 
  Command '['/home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/kinematics/env.sh', 'make', '-j6', '-l6']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/user/catkin_ws/build_isolated/motor_driver_pkg && /home/user/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/kinematics/env.sh make -j6 -l6

Command failed, exiting.
```

I have a package called kinematics, this is the CMakeLists.txt of that package

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(kinematics)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  controller_interface
  roscpp
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package()

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(kinematics 
  src/ackermann.cpp
  src/diff_drive.cpp)
target_link_libraries(kinematics ${catkin_LIBRARIES})


#############
## Install ##
#############

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)

install(TARGETS kinematics
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)
```

I have another package called motor_driver_pkg that takes uses the library "kinematics" from kinematics package. This is the CMakeLists.txt for that package.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motor_driver_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf
  kinematics
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
catkin_package()

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(include 
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${kinematics_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(dc_motor_driver src/dc_motor_driver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dc_motor_driver kinematics ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

This works completely fine with catkin_make. But fails when I run catkin_make_isolated. I understand that the motor_driver_pkg is not able to find the kinematics library. Need help. Don't know what is going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314161/catkin_make_isolated-/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find--l%3Clib_name%3E/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: change the `catkin_package()` call in the `CMakeLists.txt` of your `kinematics` package to the following:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES kinematics)
```

Refer to [Building and installing C++ libraries and headers](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html) in the Catkin documentation for more information about *exporting* information from Catkin packages.

---

Longer explanation:

> Don't know what is going wrong.

You have this in the `motor_driver_pkg`:

> ```
> target_link_libraries(dc_motor_driver kinematics ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> ```

Thing is, CMake assumes that if you provide the name of a library directly (as you do with `kinematics`) you're referring to something it calls a [*target*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html). It takes the name of the target you specify and then tries to look up information about it in its internal data structures.

If the target is defined in the same CMake *context*, this will work fine. It'll find the information it needs (such as the actual filename and path associated with that target) and then essentially replace the name of the target with whatever information is required by the particular CMake statement that the target's name is being used in.

In this case that would be the absolute path to the actual file that constitutes the `kinematics` library (probably something like `/path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/lib/kinematics/libkinematics.so` (or something like that, could be different)).

> This works completely fine with catkin_make. But fails when I run catkin_make_isolated.

So the issue here is the "CMake context": `catkin_make` combines *all* of the `CMakeLists.txt` it finds in your workspace into one and then begins the build process (it doesn't really do this, but for this explanation we're pretending it does). That creates a single context, in which the target name `kinematics` actually means something, namely: the target defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` of your `kinematics` package. So when CMake encounters the `target_link_libraries(dc_motor_driver kinematics ..)` it can look up the name `kinematics` and it'll find the information it needs to make that statement succeed.

With `catkin_make_isolated` things are completely different: as the *isolated* in the name implies, `catkin_make_isolated` does *not* coalesce all `CMakeLists.txt` into a single context, but keeps everything .. isolated.

It should now be clear why looking up the target name `kinematics` fails in this case: `kinematics` is only a defined target in the context of the `CMakeLists.txt` of your `kinematics` package. Nowhere else. So CMake fails to lookup the information it needs with the error message you show as a result.

> I understand that the motor_driver_pkg is not able to find the kinematics library

It should also be clear that `motor_driver_pkg` is not actually looking for anything. It's CMake.

---

To fix this, we need to make some information available to consuming packages that allows them to find the information (and files) they need.

For Catkin packages that would like to make libraries available to other Catkin packages, that is done by the `catkin_package(..)` statement, in particular with the `LIBRARIES` argument followed by a list of *library targets* of which the information should be exported.

Your `kinematics` package does have a `catkin_package()` statement there, but it's completely empty. So Catkin does not export any information from the `kinematics` package, leading to CMake not being able to do anything when it encounters the `kinematics` target name in the build script of `motor_driver_pkg`.

To fix this, change the `CMakeLists.txt` of `kinematics` to contain the following call to `catkin_package(..)`:

```
catkin_package(LIBRARIES kinematics)
```

(and perhaps even `catkin_package(LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME})`, as the name of the library is identical to the name of the project).

You'll probably also want to be able to export information about the include directories that are needed to be able to use the headers of `kinematics`. You'd do that as follows:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES kinematics)
```

Now consuming packages can just add `kinematics` to their `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS ..)` call and then the `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `catkin_LIBRARIES` will contain all the necessary bits for linking and compiling to succeed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
Note also that this is a CMake problem: you cannot just refer to target names that are not defined (or imported) in the current context.

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2019-01-30**:
Yes. Thank you very much. That was the issue. While linking shared libraries while performing catkin_make_isolated, we have to use the catkin_package macro and do not use target_link_libraries. It was actually working and I broke it by adding a library to the target_link_libraries.